# com.instagram.exclusivegram shows "Notes" in addition to "Instagram" in iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, instagram-api

I have an app that enables users to share via Instagram through document interaction controller. I only want to show Instagram on the list of applications, so within my code, I use the Instagram-only file extension .igo (of type com.instagram.exclusivegram as outlined in their documentation: https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/).

The following code works but after I switched to iOS9, I see that "Notes" now also appears on the applications list (instead of previously just showing Instagram). Has anyone else encountered this problem as well?

```
let image = self.imageCache.getImage(url)
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
let filePath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingString("/RPImage.igo")
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1.0)!.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)

let fileUrl = NSURL(string: "file://\(filePath)")

docController = self.setupControllerWithURL(fileUrl!, delegate: self)
docController.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
docController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1), inView: self.view, animated: true)
```

Comment: I have the same problem aswell.

Comment: I also have this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. In addition to notes, I have several other apps. "Copy to Instagram" is actually hidden off screen :(

Comment: I too had the same issue. Do we have any work around solution? Apart from "Notes" app, can we remove "More" options too?

Comment: Any news on this? We are facing the same issue at our end.